# How can I show image url from server (flask) on Android studio by okhttp

Tags: java, python, android, flask, okhttp

How can I show image URL from server (flask) on Android studio by okhttp. I write a method for return img(encode by base64) and send to my android studio by this code

```
@app.route('/', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def handle_request():
    files_ids = list(flask.request.files)
    print("\nNumber of Received Images : ", len(files_ids))
    image_num = 1
    n = 0
    for file_id in files_ids:
        print("\nSaving Image ", str(image_num), "/", len(files_ids))
        if n == 0 or file_id == 'image0':
            imagefile = flask.request.files[file_id]
            filename = werkzeug.utils.secure_filename(imagefile.filename)
            print("Image Filename : " + imagefile.filename)
            timestr = time.strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")
            path = r'C:\Users\Malee\Desktop\AndroidFlask-master\Part 1\FlaskServer\uploads'
            imagefile.save(os.path.join(path,filename))
            #os.system('python test_grader.py')
            n = n+1
        if n > 0 and n!=0:
            if file_id != 'image0':
                imagefile = flask.request.files['image'+str((len(files_ids)-1))]
                filename = werkzeug.utils.secure_filename(imagefile.filename)
                print("Image Filename : " + imagefile.filename)
                timestr = time.strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")
                path = r'C:\Users\Malee\Desktop\AndroidFlask-master\Part 1\FlaskServer\Answer'
                imagefile.save(os.path.join(path,filename))
                #os.system('python test_grader2.py')
                break

        image_num = image_num + 1
    print("\n")
    path = r'C:\Users\Malee\Desktop\AndroidFlask-master\Part 1\FlaskServer\download'
    #return send_file(os.path.join(path,newest()), mimetype='image/gif')
    path = r'C:\Users\User\Desktop\AndroidFlask-master\Part 1\FlaskServer\download'
    data_uri = base64.b64encode(open('DN.jpg', 'rb').read()).decode('utf-8')
    img_tag = '<img src="data:image/png;base64,{0}">'.format(data_uri)
    return data_uri
```

And then on my android studio response by bitmap and show on ImageView by this code

```
client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                // Cancel the post on failure.
                call.cancel();
                Log.d("FAIL", e.getMessage());

                // In order to access the TextView inside the UI thread, the code is executed inside runOnUiThread()
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        TextView responseText = findViewById(R.id.responseText);
                        responseText.setText("Failed to Connect to Server. Please Try Again.");
                    }
                });
            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call call, final Response response) throws IOException {
                // In order to access the TextView inside the UI thread, the code is executed inside runOnUiThread()
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        TextView responseText = findViewById(R.id.responseText);
                        ImageView responesImg = findViewById(R.id.imageView2);

                        /*InputStream inputStream = response.body().byteStream();
                        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);*/


                        ResponseBody in = response.body();
                        InputStream inputStream = in.byteStream();
                        Log.i("inputStream","inputstream value = "+inputStream);
                        // convert inputstram to bufferinoutstream
                        BufferedInputStream bufferedInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(inputStream);
                        Bitmap bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bufferedInputStream);
                        Log.i("bitmap","bitmap value = "+bitmap);
                        showImage(bitmap);/*
                        MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), bitmap, "test.jpg" , "none");
                        responesImg.setImageBitmap(bitmap);*/


                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

And when I run in my phone can be show the title but can't show img.

Comment: Note that `base_uri` is a misnomer. The data in this variable is the base64 encoded image, not a URI to the image.

Comment: What does your log file show? Does it show the base64 encoded string? I suspect that your problem is that you consume the stream when you call `Log.i()` so the data is no longer available when you try to create the bitmap.

Answer (score 1):

To load and show image from url to ImageView, you can use Glide library to do it

Add to your app `gradle`

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    google()
}

dependencies {
  implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.10.0'
  annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.10.0'
}
```

Load image to view:

```
  Glide.with(context).load(url).into(imageView);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your Flask server you are encoding and sending the local path where the image resides on your machine to your android app. When your android app tries to decode the response, it does not know where it is.

Suggested Solution:

1. Save your picture to a cloud based storage.(e.g Firebase or Amazon storage, etc)
2. Download your image and load it to imageView. (e.g Picasso.get().load("http://link-to-your-image").into(imageView);)

Hope that help.

Comment: "In your Flask server you are encoding and sending the local path where the image resides on your machine to your android app." From what I can tell, the Flask code opens the image and base64 encodes the binary data.